# Remainders with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $ f(x) \in C [x] .$
Suppose $ f(-1+i) = 2+5i  $   and $ f(-2-i)=-3. $
Determine the remainder of f(x) divided by $(x+1-i)(x+2+i). $

How would i begin with this question, like how would i determine what f(x) is to begin with?

Comment: Do you know how to approach this question if all if the coeffient of complex numbers were 0?

Comment: Yeah then its regular long division right?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $\displaystyle f(x)=A(x+1-i)(x+2+i)+B(x+2+i)+C(x+1-i)$

Put $x=-1+i$ and $-2-i$ one by one to find $B,C$

---

Alternatively,

let $\displaystyle f(x)=A(x+1-i)(x+2+i)+Bx+C$

Put $x=-1+i$ and $-2-i$ one by one to find $B,C$

In either cases,  $B,C$ are arbitrary constants and $A$ is a polynomial

Comment: What are $A,B,C$? Numbers? Polynomials?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, arbitrary constants independent of $x$

Comment: So, you are assuming $f$ is a quadratic?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, sorry $B,C$ are arbitrary constants, $A$ is  a polynomial

Comment: Maybe that information should be edited into your answer.